# Saving cascade with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have the following entities and I'm trying to save them using hibernate cascade:

Entity `Usuario`:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="system", name="usuarios")
public class Usuario {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nome;
    @Column(name = "data_nascimento")
    private Date dataNascimento;
    private String sexo;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "usuario")
    private DadosFuncionario dadosFuncionario;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public Date getDataNascimento() {
        return dataNascimento;
    }
    public void setDataNascimento(Date dataNascimento) {
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }
    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }
    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }
    public DadosFuncionario getDadosFuncionario() {
        return dadosFuncionario;
    }
    public void setDadosFuncionario(DadosFuncionario dadosFuncionario) {
        this.dadosFuncionario = dadosFuncionario;
    }
}
```

Table structure for `usuarios`:

```
CREATE TABLE "system"."usuarios" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "data_nascimento" date,
    "nome" varchar(255) COLLATE "default" NOT NULL,
    "sexo" varchar(255) COLLATE "default"
)
```

Entity `DadosFuncionario`:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "system", name = "dados_funcionario")
public class DadosFuncionario {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String matricula;
    @Column(name = "pref_reg", nullable = true)
    private int prefReg;
    @Column(name = "pref_dep", nullable = false)
    private int prefDep;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String telefone;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario")
    private Usuario usuario;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }
    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
    public int getPrefReg() {
        return prefReg;
    }
    public void setPrefReg(int prefReg) {
        this.prefReg = prefReg;
    }
    public int getPrefDep() {
        return prefDep;
    }
    public void setPrefDep(int prefDep) {
        this.prefDep = prefDep;
    }
    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }
    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }
    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }
    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
}
```

Table structure for `dados_funcionario`:

```
CREATE TABLE "system"."dados_funcionario" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "matricula" varchar(255) COLLATE "default",
    "pref_dep" int4 NOT NULL,
    "pref_reg" int4,
    "telefone" varchar(255) COLLATE "default",
    "id_usuario" int4
)
```

And then to test if it was saving everything the way it was supposed to, I'm doing this:

```
Usuario novoUsuario = new Usuario();
DadosFuncionario novoDadosFuncionario = new DadosFuncionario();

novoDadosFuncionario.setMatricula("XXXXXXXXX");
novoDadosFuncionario.setPrefDep(9999);
novoUsuario.setNome("XXXXX XXXXX");             
novoUsuario.setDadosFuncionario(novoDadosFuncionario);

Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(novoUsuario);
tx.commit();
```

It insert the correct data into the correct tables, but it does not save the foreign key of `usuarios` in `dados_funcionario` (its filling the column `id_usuario` with `null`). So, it understands the relationship (it saved in cascade, because I only used the session.save() with `novoUsuario` and it saved the data from `novoDadosFuncionario`) but it doesn't insert the foreign key and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the other side of the relation anywhere, which you should in bidirectional relationships. Add this

```
novoDadosFuncionario.setUsuario(novoUsuario);
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe that I didn't thought that... So simple... I think it's time to have a break and drink some coffee. Thanks!! Saved my morning!